# Can I configure the android sdk distributed with adt eclipse bundle to use with Intellij Idea?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adt

I have been using the adt bundel wth eclipse fpr android development for quite some time now. I recently started using the community edition of Intelli J. Version 13.1. I was wondering if there is a way to use the android sdk in the adt tools( I had downloaded the zipped file) to use with IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use it with Intellij. You can even download Android Studio which is specifically for Android and based on Intellij.

To start an Android project in Intellij you need to need to create a project and it'll guide you with these steps.

1. Create a new project
2. Enter the project name, choose Android as the project type.
3. Set your JDK location
4. Set Android SDK location

That's it!